# Installation j2sdk_1.4.2_02 on ubuntu fails

Tags: java, ubuntu

When I try to install the sdk on *ubuntu 14.04 lts* I get the following:

> Unpacking...
>   tail: cannot open ‘+486’ for reading: No such file or directory
>   Checksumming...
>   1
>   The download file appears to be corrupted.  Please refer
>   to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation
>   Instructions on the download page for more information.
>   Please do not attempt to install this archive file.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Well for one, this version of Java is horribly outdated. Get the most recent version from the download page at [Oracle](https://java.com/en/download/).

Comment: Install a newer version of Java, or an older version of ubuntu.

Comment: Hmm. You have a shell script there, which uses the old `tail` syntax. Can you edit it? If so, try to replace all places where there is a `tail +number` to `tail -n +number` and see if that works.